# Is Moksham guaranteed if have Phanchasamskaram done for me?

Tags: rituals

Is Moksha guaranteed if I have Pancha Samskaram (Samashrayanam) done for me? I heard that Perumal promised Swamy Ramanujacharya that anyone who has Pancha Samskaram (Samashrayanam) done will get Moksha. Is that true?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Personal advice questions aren't allowed on this site, so I'm temporarily putting your question on hold.  If you want to remove the personal details and make the question more general, then edit it and flag me to reopen it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited it.

Comment: OK, I reopened it.

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra - It is matter of extreme faith or Mahaviswasa in Lord. So, in short, Samasrayanam and Bharasamarpanam will surely lead to Moksha. Swami Desikan and Swami Pillai Lokacharyar in their Rahasya granthas have written extensively on it. Please approach a SriVaishnava acharya and try to read them to have a better understanding. It is matter of absolute faith in the redemption power of the almighty. As Krishna says in Bhagavad Gita " sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaḿ śaraṇaḿ vraja ahaḿ tvāḿ sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ"

Comment: @NikihilRaghavendra - Please check the link provided below. Hope it helps in clarifying your doubt or doubts, at least to some extent.                             http://anudinam.org/2013/09/10/pancha-samskara-samasrayanam-a-dialogue/

Comment: @Krishna, Thanks for the link, that helped me understand more about Samashrayanam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What is Samashrayanam?

> Samashrayanam can be defined as a process or custom in Sri Vaishnava Sampradaya  'to approach (Acharya) with  sincerity'. During the process of Samashrayanam, the Acharya takes the person    as his shishya or disciple, irrespective of his caste, creed or other differences. Concurrently, it is also expected that the shishya is to live as per the wishes of the Acharya. Thus the person gets the link to the rich Sri Vaishnava heritage. The most revered Pancha Samskaram is performed when one takes the process of Samashrayanam.

## What about the life after taking the process of Samashrayanam?

> Samashrayanam is indeed a great turning point in the life of Jeevathma, who has got entangled in the maze of life and death.  The Pancha Samskaram (or the five-fold-purification) performed is invaluable. But , one has to keep up the Samskaram by his regular devotional activities. The Pancha Samskarams performed to the person loses significance and potential, if he gets involved in worldly activites and pleasures throwing more indifference to the Paramatman(Sriman Narayana). After all, the ultimate purpose of Pancha Samskaram is to make a person eligible to take part in the various activities of the Sanatana Dharma and to serve the Divya Dhampathi (Sriman Narayana and His consort, Sri Mahalakshmi). Sharanagadhi towards the Lord must be the only objective in our life.  Samashrayanam helps in a great way to make a person progress towards achieving this goal.

[Pancha Samskaram (Samashrayanam)](http://www.mudaliandan.com/samashrayanam.php)

[Sources1](http://anudinam.org/2013/09/10/pancha-samskara-samasrayanam-a-dialogue/)

[Sources2](http://www.angelfire.com/de/bhakthimargam/faqsamash.html)